# What creates CPU I/O wait but no disk operations?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, io

I have CPU I/O wait steady around 50%, but when I run `iostat 1` it shows little to no disk activity.

What causes wait without iops?

NOTE: There no NFS or FUSE filesystems here, but it is using Xen virtualization.

[image]

Comment: What distro? What version?

Comment: Also: is this a the Xen hyper visor machine or a VM with the iowaits?

Comment: Does `iotop` show you anything?

Answer (score 7):

NFS can do this, and it wouldn't surprise me if other network filesystems (and even FUSE-based devices) had similar effects.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case there's no NFS and no FUSE.  I'll add that to the question too.

Answer (score 6):

Is there any chance other VMs on the server are thrashing the disk?

I know with virtualisation that you can get some strange results if the host node is overloaded.

Comment: True but that should be in steal% instead of io% right?  Or can it cross over there too?

Comment: Steal happens when there's less CPU capacity available than requested by the VMs. If the physical disk is overloaded, your processes are going to spend a lot of time in iowait waiting for their turn at the disk even if they're not hitting the disk much.

Comment: Yeah, this. See another question with the same answer at http://serverfault.com/a/209031/57468

Answer (score 3):

If this is the Amazon EC2 Xen environment using instance-based storage, ask Amazon to check the health of the host containing this image.

If this is a Xen environment that you can gain access to the hypervisor, then check the IOwait from without for the disk image (file, network, LVM-slice, whatever) being used for the xvda and xvdb devices.  You'll also want to check the I/O system, in general, for the hypervisor since other disk devices might be monopolizing the system's resources.

```
iostat -txk 5
```

is usually a good starting diagnostic tool.  It takes 5-second summaries of I/O for ALL devices available to it, and thus is useful both with-in and wither-out the VM image.

Answer (score 2):

Check your available file descriptors / inodes. When you hit the limit, they swap and mimic iowait

Edit

I saw you are using xen, have a look at your current interrupts, you might find blkif is higher than normal.

Bit late now, but get munin installed and it will really help future debugging.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo sysctl vm.block_dump=1
```

Then check dmesg to see what is performing block read / writes or dirtying inodes.

Also check nofile limit in limits.conf, a process could be requesting more files than it is permitted to open.

Answer (score 1):

## WARNING: HDPARM IS DANGEROUS, ALWAYS READ ABOUT THE COMMAND YOU ARE GOING TO USE!

If no other **virtual** machines are stressing the hard disk(s), do

```
hdparm -f
```

on the underlying physical disk(s). Possibly the disk cache don't work accurately. This will flush the data stored in the cache, and you can constantly monitoring the I/O, whether it is about to rise again after the flush. If yes, it will be a cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

With load average, I've seen blocked networking operations (i.e. long calls to an external DB server) increase. I don't know for sure but I'm guessing network IO can cause CPU wait to go up? Can anyone confirm?

Comment: In most modern machines, no. Most, if not all recent systems have DMA-capable NICs to prevent precisely this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could be loopback devices, that are themselves mounted over the network.

Answer (score 0):

On my machines NFS is the biggest IO-WAIT "producer". I have a SSD in my laptop which is fast as hell, so "real IO" is not the problem. Nevertheless I have sometimes lots of IO wait due to my mounted nfs shares.

SCP sometimes also seems to lead to IO Wait but to a far lesser extend.

Answer (score 0):

This can be anything. It just means that something is waiting for end of I/O operation. You can figure out what process it is via ps, then attach gdb to it and check out backtrace to determine which call is hang (usually this is some network-related stuff or suddenly disconnected disk). For fd info, check out /proc.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced a similar problem right before a **disk in a RAID failed** and some **SATA cables with tight bends** in them started failing.

The CPU usage was near 0%, but 1 or more CPU's on a 4-core system were spending 100% of their time in IOwait for extended periods of time (found via `top` multi-line cpu display) with very low IOps and bandwidth (found via `iostat`), but bursty high interrupt activity.  Interactive command-line use was painful during any disk access (i.e. auto-save from someone's `emacs` session) but otherwise tolerable once the periods of IOwait passed (and presumably the operations succeeded after many retries).